# How Kernel Identifies the format of downloading doc before it gets downloaded?

Tags: linux, kernel

In Unix, When we want to download any document from the internet, it asks us to save the document as and it give the format of the document(e.g. : .pdf, .mp3...etc).
Then, how kernel come to know the format of that document even we have not downloaded it yet?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the kernel, the web server serving the file tells the browser what MIME type it is and optionally what filename to use.

Taking your own avatar as an example, these are the headers returned by the Gravatar web server:

```
$ curl -I https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/da4d09ebbb789ea0442c6cf98cca8649\?s\=32\&d\=identicon\&r\=PG\&f\=1
HTTP/2.0 200
server:nginx
date:Tue, 21 Feb 2017 17:04:38 GMT
content-type:image/png
content-length:914
last-modified:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 08:00:00 GMT
link:<https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/da4d09ebbb789ea0442c6cf98cca8649?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1>; rel="canonical"
access-control-allow-origin:*
x-nc:HIT lhr 1
accept-ranges:bytes
expires:Tue, 21 Feb 2017 17:09:38 GMT
cache-control:max-age=300
source-age:817
```

The relevant line is the `content-type:image/png` line; this tells the browser that the file is a PNG image, and the browser uses that to build an appropriate filename (using the end of the URL, and `.png`). A filename can be provided using a different header entry.

This information is available in the HTTP headers, before a single byte of the file itself is downloaded.

Comment: not satisfied ..i need more information..thank you

Comment: how can file itself tell the browser about its own information?

Comment: The file itself doesn't tell the browser, the web server tells the browser. See my update.

Comment: Well, actually the web browser reads the "magic bytes" of the file, uses that to determine the content type, and sends a header with the info.  Mac and Linux do this for opening files locally as well.  Only Windows is dependent on the file extension to determine what to do wtih a file...

Comment: @ivanivan no, the browser isn't involved in determining the file type. But I'm not sure where you think I claimed the extension was used to determine the file type...

Comment: Sorry, brain got ahead of my fingers.  Web server reads magic bytes to determine content type to send as header.  Never implied that you mentioned using the extension of the file, just added it in for completeness as to what happens when a file is double clicked on your local machine....

Comment: @ivanivan sorry for my overreaction, thanks for the extra info. Note that many servers still rely on the extension to determine the content type, they don't sniff (see [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html) for example).

Comment: @Stephen Kitt Can u please do one favor on me?..Can u please give the short description of the fields in HTTP header that you mentioned in you answer? So that i'll learn more.

Comment: @Andy.inamdar that's not how this site works — it's a Q&A site, so this answer addresses your question above, that's all; if you have further questions, you should ask other questions, separately. (But note that we do expect you to put some effort into things as well, so you should try reading up on the HTTP headers by yourself. "Into things" includes "how this site works"; please take the [tour] too!)